# Data mining with postgres in production environment - is there a better way?

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, bigdata, data-mining

There is a web application which is running for a years and during its life time the application has gathered a lot of user data. Data is stored in relational DB (postgres). Not all of this data is needed to run application (to do the *business*). However form time to time business people ask me to provide reports of this data data. And this causes some problems:

1. sometimes these SQL queries are long running
2. quires are executed against production DB (not cool)
3. not so easy to deliver reports on weekly or monthly base
4. some parts of data is stored in way which is not suitable for such
   querying (queries are inefficient)

My idea (note that I am a developer not the data mining specialist) how to improve this whole process of delivering reports is:

1. create separate DB which regularly is update with production data
2. optimize how data is stored
3. create a dashboard to present reports

**Question:** But is there a better way? Is there another DB which better fits for such data analysis? Or should I look into *modern* data mining tools?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you *really* do data mining (as in: classification, clustering, anomaly detection), or is "data mining" for you any reporting on the data? In the latter case, all the "modern data mining tools" will disappoint you, because they serve a different purpose.

Have you used the indexing functionality of Postgres well? Your scenario sounds as if *selection and aggregation* are most of the work, and SQL databases are excellent for this - if well designed.

For example, materialized views and triggers can be used to process data into a scheme more usable for your reporting.

Comment: Regarding your question "Have you used the indexing functionality of Postgres well?". Yes also indexes are missing. This also will be fixed in second DB.

Answer (score 4):

There are a thousand ways to approach this issue but I think that the path of least resistance for you would be postgres replication. Check out this [Postgres replication](http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2013/02/16/zero-to-postgresql-streaming-replication-in-10-mins/) tutorial for a quick, proof-of-concept. (There are many hits when you Google for postgres replication and that link is just one of them.) Here is a link documenting [streaming replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) from the PostgreSQL site's wiki.

I am suggesting this because it meets all of your criteria and also stays withing the bounds of the technology you're familiar with. The only learning curve would be the replication part.

Replication solves your issue because it would create a second database which would effectively become your "read-only" db which would be updated via the replication process. You would keep the schema the same but your indexing could be altered and reports/dashboards customized. This is the database you would query. Your main database would be your transactional database which serves the users and the replicated database would serve the stakeholders.

This is a wide topic, so please do your diligence and research it. But it's also something that can work for you and can be quickly turned around.

Comment: Thx for your opinion! I believe I will use second DB for data analysis.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want try Data Mining with PostgreSQL there are some tools which can be used.

1. The very simple way is [KNIME](http://www.knime.org/). It is easy to install. It has full featured Data Mining tools. You can access your data directly from database, process and save it back to database.
2. Hardcore way is [MADLib](http://madlib.apache.org/). It installs Data Mining functions in Python and C directly in Postgres so you can mine with SQL queries.

Both projects are stable enough to try it.

Answer (score 1):

For reporting, we use non-transactional (read only) database. We don't care about normalization. If I were you, I would use another database for reporting. I will desing the tables following OLAP principals, (star schema, snow flake), and use an ETL tool to dump the data periodically (may be weekly) to the read only database to start creating reports.

Reports are used for decision support, so they don't have to be in realtime, and usually don't have to be current. In other words it is acceptable to create report up to last week or last month.